# Pandas and Numpy program slower than loop version of same functionality, how to speed up?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, parallel-processing, vectorization

I have millions of records with each record having an integer (p) and a X*3 matrix of values. For each record, the goal is to find a row from the matrix by selection criteria (see the if-statements in the code).

I'm fairly new to Python and try to make use of vectorization in Pandas using parallel computations instead of loops. I have written the program in two versions, one with Pandas+Numpy and another one with simple loops.

I was told that using vectorization and Numpy array operations is faster than loops. But so far, the loop version is about 10x faster:
[image]

Here is the program:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import time

d = {
    'values': [np.array([[1400,1400,1800000],[1500,1505,4800000],[1300,1305,5000]]), np.array([[800,900,80000],[1400,1420,50000],[1250,1300,60000]]), np.array([[1700,1750,5000000],[1900,1950,5000000],[1600,1600,3000000]]), np.array([])],
    'p': [1300, 1350, 1800, 1400]
}

# The Pandas+Numpy version

def selection_numpy(row):
    try:
        # Select rows where col[0] >= p
        c1 = row['values'][row['values'][:,0] >= row['p']]  

        # Select rows where col[2] > 1000000     
        c2 = c1[c1[:,2]>1000000]

        # Sort by col[0] and return the lowest row
        return c2[c2[:,0].argsort()][0]
    except:
        pass


start = time.time()

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df['result'] = df.apply(selection_numpy, axis=1)
# print(df.head())
print(time.time()-start)

# The loop version:

def selection_loop(values, p):
    lowest_num = 9999999999
    lowest_item = None

    # Iterate through each row in the matrix and replace lowest_item if it's lower than the previous one
    for item in values:
        if item[0] >= p and item[2] > 1000000 and item[0] < lowest_num:
            lowest_num = item[0]
            lowest_item = item

    return lowest_item

start = time.time()

d['result'] = []
for i in range(0, 4):
    result = selection_loop(d['values'][i], d['p'][i])
    d['result'].append(result)
# print(d['result'])
print(time.time()-start)
```

Both produce the same result values, but the loop version is magnitudes faster (for the actual million record dataset, not for the 4 example records).

I assume there is a simple and elegant solution to find the desired row for each record which uses vectorization and is the fastest. Not sure why the function using Numpy arrays is so slow, but I appreciate any guidance.

Comment: You forgot to define `parameters`. People can't run it otherwise

Comment: Oops, code updated. I replaced the parameter values by static numbers in the example

Comment: `apply` is much slower than a python loop.  You shouldn't be storing numpy arrays in columns either, it's inefficient.

Comment: Oh ok, this image says Numpy > Pandas > apply > iterrows > loops, wondering how to implement this program in numpy+pandas then, the right way? https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1600/1*p4zjrqG97C4bFmOXU5UQog.png

Comment: The point is that you should avoid storing non-numeric values in the cells of a DataFrame whenever possible. Dictionaries, lists, and arrays don't belong in a DataFrame. The most complex object type you should generally be putting into one is a `string`.

Comment: Ok got it, is there any faster way than loops? Cython compiled loops? Multiprocessing? This is still incredible slow, for X million records.